# Ich/wir im Südtiroler Dialekt

Tags: dialect, personal-pronoun, south-tyrol

Ich habe gestern im Fernsehen einen Krimi gesehen, der in Südtirol gespielt hat (ORF-Landkrimi Südtirol »Endabrechnung«). Im Film wird Südtiroler Dialekt gesprochen. In einer Szene wird die Hauptfigur, Commissario Höllbacher, gebeten, seine Handynummer zu nennen, worauf dieser sagt:

> mia hon khoa händy

Aus dem Kontext geht sehr eindeutig hervor, dass Höllbacher ausdrücklich nur von sich selbst als Einzelperson spricht (also nicht von sich als Mitglied einer Gruppe). Ein sehr ähnlich klingender Satz in Wiener Dialekt könnte lauten:

> wia hom ka händy

Wobei das erste Wort (»wia«) auch wie (»mia«) klingen kann. Dieser Satz lautet auf Hochdeutsch aber:

> Wir haben kein Handy.

Das Subjekt steht also ganz klar im Plural. Im Film hat der Commissario aber ganz eindeutig von sich allein, also von einer einzelnen Person gesprochen, daher hätte ich eher erwartet, etwas in dieser Art zu hören:

> i hon khoa händy

Das erste Wort war aber ein deutlich hörbares »mia«. Auch an anderen Stellen im Film fiel auf, dass Personen, als sie über sich selbst sprachen, statt des erwarteten Singular-Pronomens »i« gelegentlich das Pronomen »mia« verwendeten, das ich aus anderen bayrischen Dialekten aber nur als Plural-Wort kenne.

An anderen Stellen hört man aber immer wieder das Pronomen »i«, wenn Personen von sich selbst sprachen. Ich vermute daher, dass die Verwendung von »mia« als Personalpronomen für die erste Person im Singular an bestimmte Bedingungen geknüpft ist.

Meine Fragen:

- Unter welchen Umständen ersetzt man im Südtiroler Dialekt das Personalpronomen »i« durch »mia«?
- Gibt es dieses Phänomen auch in anderen deutschen Dialekten?
- Liegt hier vielleicht ein Einfluss aus dem Italienischen vor? (Südtirol hat zwei Amtssprachen: Deutsch und Italienisch)

---

### Klarstellung

(Am 5.1.2016; Notwendig geworden, weil viele gerne eine Frage beantworten wollen, die hier gar nicht gestellt wird)

Es geht in dieser Frage ganz ausdrücklich **nicht** darum, dass in vielen bairischen Dialekten das Personalpronomen, das Hochdeutsch »*wir*« lautet, als »*mia*« ausgesprochen wird. Das ist im gesamten süddeutschen Raum und in ganz Österreich so. (Wobei es vermutlich auch Ausnahmen geben wird.)

Da meine erste Muttersprache genau so ein Dialekt ist, ist mir das seit über 50 Jahren bestens bekannt. Danach frage ich also ganz ausdrücklich **nicht**.

Ich frage:

Warum wird in der Gegend von Bozen und Meran in bestimmten Fällen die eigentlich angebrachte Einzahl durch die Mehrzahl ersetzt?

Wenn ich das ins Hochdeutsche übersetze: Warum sagt der Darsteller, wenn er nur sich allein meint, den Satz

> **Wir** haben kein Handy.

Warum sagt er nicht das was die meisten Leute erwarten würden, nämlich

> **Ich** habe kein Handy.

Und weil auch das unklar zu sein scheint:

Aus dem Kontext geht klar und unmissverständlich hervor, dass er nicht für eine Gruppe spricht zu der er gehört. Es ist also **nicht** gemeint:

> <del>Wir von der Polizei haben keine Handys.</del>

Der Sprecher meint im Gegenteil ausdrücklich nur sich alleine. Er meint:

> **Ich**, Commissario Höllbacher, habe kein Handy, denn ich habe es vor einigen Tagen von einer hohen Brücke in einen Fluss geworfen, und ich möchte unerreichbar bleiben.

sagt aber:

> **Wir** haben kein Handy.
>   **mia** hob khoa händy

Warum?

---

### Noch mehr Kontext

(Ergänzung vom 11. Jänner 2017)

Der Film »Endabrechnung« (ein ORF-Landkrimi) ist in der ORF TV-Thek leider nicht mehr verfügbar. Ich habe den Film (Gesamtdauer: 90 Minuten) aber für private Zwecke noch rechtzeitig heruntergeladen, und habe drei kurze Ausschnitte extrahiert (15, 24 und 21 Sekunden lang), in denen Sätze zu hören sind, in denen der Sprecher von sich selbst im Plural spricht. Um die jeweilige Situation zu verstehen, habe ich auch einige Szenen zusammengefasst, so weit sie für die Fragestellung von Belang sind.

Im Vorspann wird die Vorgeschichte erzählt:

Der aalglatte Oberstaatsanwalt Nicoletti (Tobias Moretti) ermuntert den bodenständigen Commissario Höllbacher (Robert Palfrader) vor der versammelten Presse, den Namen eines Tatverdächtigen zu nennen. Es ist ein Pfarrer. Als sich der Pfarrer erhängt, sich wenig später aber dessen Unschuld herausstellt, fühlt sich Höllbacher für dessen Tod verantwortlich. Er fühlt sich aber auch von Staatsanwalt Nicoletti hintergangen, der sich aus der Affäre zieht und Höllbacher die alleinige Schuld zuschiebt. Höllbacher knallt Waffe und Dienstmarke auf Nicolettis Tisch und verlässt dessen Büro mit den Worten: »I scheiß auf euch olle«.

In der darauffolgenden Nacht (Höllbacher ist noch immer glatt rasiert) bleibt er mit seinem Auto ohne erkennbaren Grund mitten auf einer sehr hohen Brücke stehen, steigt aus und wirft sein Handy in die Tiefe.
(Ende von Vorspann und Vorgeschichte)
(In einer späteren Szene erzählt er einem Freund, dass er nicht mehr der Knecht seines Handys sein wollte.)

Am Beginn der Haupthandlung sieht man Höllbacher mit schütterem ungepflegtem Vollbart und mit ungepflegtem Haar. Auch seine Kleidung wirkt heruntergekommen. Die Haupthandlung spielt also einige Zeit (Wochen? Monate?) nachdem er sich seines Handys entledigt hat.

In Meran passiert ein Mord. Einem Bankdirektor wird ins Gesicht geschossen. Die Vize Questorin Anna Thaler hat die Aufgabe den Mord aufzuklären, aber sie und ihre Kollegen haben wenig Erfahrung mit solchen Fällen. Daher sucht sie Höllbacher auf, doch dieser lehnt die Bitte um Unterstützung ab. Höllbacher bezeichnet sich selbst in dieser Szene als »kein Polizist mehr«, Anna stellt aber klar, dass er nur im Krankenstand ist.

Höllbacher erfährt wenige Stunden später, dass der verhasste Oberstaatsanwalt Nicoletti den Fall übernommen hat. Er geht daraufhin ins Kommissariat, wo er Anna wieder trifft. Anna und ein junger Kollege überreden Höllbacher, sich Bilder vom Tatort anzusehen. Er tut ihnen diesen Gefallen, will dann aber gleich wieder gehen. Schnell bittet ihn der junge Kriminalbeamte noch für eventuelle Nachfragen um seine Telefonnummer, und da fällt das erste Mal der Satz

> Mia hon khoa Händy.

(Hochdeutsch: »Wir haben kein Handy.«)

Diese Szene habe ich extrahiert und auf meinen Server hochgeladen:

- [Mia_hon_khoa_handy_1.mp4](https://hubert.schoelnast.at/videos/Mia_hon_khoa_handy_1.mp4) (Dauer: 15 Sekunden)

Der erste Satz von Höllbacher in diesem Ausschnitt ist übrigens:

> Also, i pocks.

(Wörtlich: »Also, ich packe es«. Sinngemäß: »Nun denn, ich breche auf.«)

Hier spricht er von sich selbst also (wie auch die meiste Zeit über) im Singular. Erst auf die Frage nach der Telefonnummer wendet er den Plural an.

Wie zu erwarten nimmt Höllbacher den Fall trotzdem an. Die Ermittlungen führen ihn in ein Hotel, wo er ein Zimmermädchen befragt. In dieser Szene fällt derselbe Satz ein zweites Mal:

- [Mia_hon_khoa_handy_2.mp4](https://hubert.schoelnast.at/videos/Mia_hon_khoa_handy_2.mp4) (Dauer: 24 Sekunden)

In dieser Szene bin ich mir aber unsicher, ob er wirklich »mia« oder doch »i« sagt. (Der letzte Satz des Zimmermädchens ist übrigens nicht deutsch, sondern vermutlich serbisch oder bosnisch, also bitte nicht wundern, wenn man ihn nicht versteht.)

Im Lauf der folgenden Handlung passieren weitere Morde. Höllbacher wird klar wer der Täter ist. Er fährt zu ihm und wird von ihm bereits erwartet. Dieses Mal ist es der Täter, der von sich selbst im Plural spricht. Diesmal besteht kein Zweifel. Der Sprecher sagt ganz eindeutig nicht »i« (*ich*) sondern ganz klar »mia« (also »wir«). Zu hören in diesem Ausschnitt:

- [Mia_hon_auf_di_gewartet.mp4](https://hubert.schoelnast.at/videos/Mia_hon_auf_di_gewartet.mp4) (Dauer: 21 Sekunden)

Der Dialog in diesem Ausschnitt lautet:

> *Mörder:* Mia hon auf di gewartet.
>   *Commissario:* Weils di schtelln willscht?
>   *Mörder:* Weil du mi jez vileicht vasteasch?

Hochdeutsche Übersetzung:

> *Mörder:* Wir haben auf dich gewartet.
>   *Commissario:* Weil du dich stellen willst?
>   *Mörder:* Weil du mich jetzt vielleicht verstehst?

Auch hier fällt auf, dass der Sprecher von sich selbst einmal im Plural spricht (***Wir*** haben gewartet), dann aber gleich wieder im Singular (*Weil du **mich** vielleicht verstehst*).

**Zum Abschluss nochmals meine Frage:**

Unter welchen Umständen ersetzt man im Südtiroler Dialekt das Personalpronomen »i« durch »mia«?

Comment: Wer selbst recherchieren möchte: ORF-Landkrimi »Endabrechnung« mit Robert Palfrader und Tobias Moretti, 90 Minuten lang, bis 29.12.2016 in der ORF-TV-Thek: http://tvthek.orf.at/profile/Endabrechnung/13886636/Endabrechnung/13899996

Comment: Ohne den Film gesehen zu haben, finde ich spontan das konkrete Beispiel nicht so ungewöhnlich. Wobei ich das so interpretiere, dass hier nicht auf sich selbst Bezug genommen wird, sondern auf die ganze Südtiroler Polizei. Also an der Stelle, wo er nach der Nummer gefragt wird, antwortet er "Wir bei der Polizei in Südtirol haben keine Handys". Dies steht in deutlichem Kontrast zu "Nur ich habe kein Handy, die Kollegen aber schon." — Ob das nun Sinn macht, dafür müsste ich den Film sehen.

Comment: @Em1: Dann schau dir doch bitte die Szene an. Ich habe mir die ersten Minuten noch einmal angesehen. Da wird ansonsten immer »i« gesagt. Bei 17:47 fällt dann der Satz »mia hon khoa händy«. Höllbacher ist zu diesem Zeitpunkt kein Polizist (er war es früher, hatte ein Burnout und wird in dieser Szene gerade als Berater angeworben). Die Aussage bezieht sich ganz klar nur auf ihn selbst, das geht aus dem Kontext sehr eindeutig hervor.

Comment: Derselbe Satz (»mia hon khoa händy«) fällt übrigens auch bei 25:39. Auch hier geht aus dem Kontext sehr eindeutig hervor, dass der Sprecher nur über sich allein spricht.

Comment: Also sooo deutlich ist mir das "mia" bei 25:39 nicht. Ich habe es jetzt zehnmal zugehört und ich höre immer wieder nur "i". Ausserdem steht im Untertext "ich", was die Erklärung von @Em1 unwahrscheinich macht. Sonst sind die Tiroler ja für ihre Tendenz Fremde zu duzen bekannt, was ja nicht im Film veranschaulicht wird

Comment: Ich hab' mir den Film auch angeschaut (danke für den Tipp übrigens - Ich mag den Südtiroler Dialekt und der Krimi war auch nicht schlecht). Ich min mir in beiden Fällen auch nicht sicher, ob er wirklich "mia" sagt. Und wo ist überhaupt @splattne, wenn man ihn braucht?

Comment: Glasklarste Begründung (für mich) warum da der Plural verwendet wird: Er sagt *hon* und nicht *hob* (was ich bei *i* erwartet hätte). Allerdings beziehen sich beide Sätze (hab sie gerade angeschaut) eindeutig auf ihn. Ich bin ratlos.

Comment: @Jan: Ich glaube nicht, dass das Wort »hob« Bestandteil des Südtiroler Dialekts ist. Ich glaube vielmehr, dass »hob« und »hon« in unterschiedlichen Regionen verwendet werden und sowohl im Singular als auch im Plural verwendet werden.

Comment: Hm, das könnte wohl auch sein … In unserem Eck wird klar zwischen den beiden unterschieden.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Hast du schon an den Pluralis Majestatis gedacht, der manchmal benutzt wird um eine  Sache zu unterstreichen oder auch die eigene Ablehnung zu dem Umstand zu unterstreichen: Wir, die Polizei, haben *doch* keine Handys. Gerne auch von Personen mit Persönlichkeitsstörungen verwendet, aber das scheint hier wohl nicht der Fall, wenn auch Burnout. ;-)

Comment: @Thomas: Robert Palfrader spielt auch den Kaiser in der ORF-Langzeit-Talkshow »Wir sind Kaiser« (wird derzeit viermal pro Jahr produziert). Dort verwirrt er als Kaiser sehr wohl seine Gäste mit dem Pluralis Majestatis, aber das hier ist eine ganz andere Rolle, die nur zufällig vom selben Schauspieler verkörpert wird. Der Commissario Höllbacher ist in dieser Szene, wie bereits ausdrücklich angemerkt, **KEIN** Polizist, sondern steht als Einzelperson der Polizei gegenüber, und sagt als Einzelperson, dass er kein Handy hat (er hat es, als er aus dem Polizeidienst ausgetreten ist, weggeworfen).

Comment: Han mia mal versucht den ORF zu kontaktieren, und den Schreiberling zu befragen? Mein ja nur, die Frage hat so gesehen eine möglichst sichere Antwort. Ob die denn auch fundiert sei, mag dahinstehen. Merke, Keltisch hat stand der Wissenschaft kein "Ich" sondern ausschließlich einen reflex von \*me; die Halstadtkultur liegt nahe. Ergo, entweder sind die äußerst modest, wie das You-nited Kingdom, oder es liegt Konttinuierlicher Sprachübergang ins Oberdeutsche vor, sofern nicht Rainer Zufall am Werk war. (Habe ich nicht genau das schon mal hier geschrieben?)

Comment: Acht Jahre nach deiner Frage ( ;) ) könnte ich mir inzwischen vorstellen, dass Höllbacher ein bißchen schuldbewusst ist und die "Untat", sein Handy vernichtet zu haben, wie ein kleiner Junge nicht auf nur seine eigene Person, sondern auf eine imaginäre Gruppe abwälzt, die es gar nicht gibt (Wie der Franzl, der sagt "Mia hom nix gmacht")

Comment: @tofro: Das ergibt keinen Sinn. Es ergibt weder für deinen kleinen Franzl einen Sinn (was für eine imaginäre Gruppe sollte das sein?), noch für Commissario Höllbacher (ich glaube nicht, dass sich Höllbacher als Mitglied der Gruppe der anonymen Handyvernichter sieht), und schon gar nicht für den Mörder, der ja ganz alleine auf Höllbacher gewartet hat. (Hast du dir die verlinkten Video-Ausschnitte angesehen?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ich denke, es handelt sich hier um die übertriebene Verwendung des Bescheidenheitsplurals (Pluralis Modestiae<sup>[(1)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluralis_Modestiae)</sup>), die sich im Dialekt eingeschliffen hat. Die Verwendung von "wir" soll die Aussage verharmlosen. In anderen Regionen ist das aber auch zu beobachten; ich würde es deswegen mehr als allgemeines Stilmittel betrachten und nicht als regionale Besonderheit. Siehe auch "[Synekdoche](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synekdoche)".

Comment: Im verlinkten Artikel wird unter »Plural steht für Singular« nur der Pluralis Majestatis angeführt. Der Sprecher gibt aber nicht vor ein Adeliger zu sein. Den Bescheidenheitsplural gibt es zwar auch (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluralis_Modestiae ), damit will der Sprecher aber von der eignen Person ablenken. (Lehrer rechnet an der Tafel vor: »*Wir* addieren diese Zahlen« obwohl nur er allein die Zahlen addiert.) Das trifft hier nicht zu. Höllbacher will nicht von sich ablenken, denn er macht eine Aussage über genau sich selbst. Auch Pl. Auctoris und Pl. benevolentiae kommen nicht in Frage.

Comment: Deine Antwort ist zwar bisher die beste, überzeugt mich aber trotzdem leider wenig. Kannst du vielleicht Beispiele anführen um deine Vermutung zu untermauern?

Comment: Wie schon gesagt: _übertriebene_ Verwendung in der Umgangssprache bzw. Dialekt, die sich daraus entwickelt hat. Es ist halt schick so zu reden...

Comment: @äöü: Das Argument »Es ist halt schick so zu reden« kann man in diesem Fall auch ausschließen. Commissario Höllbacher ist alles andere als schick, vor allem in der Szene, in der er diesen Satz zum ersten Mal sagt. Er war immer schon ein bodenständiger Mensch, und er hat einige Zeit davor seinen Dienst quittiert. Seitdem hat er sich gehen lassen. Er ist unrasiert, trägt schäbige Kleidung und sein Haar ist nicht frisiert. Und er spricht auch so wie er aussieht. Er verachtet die Bozener Schickeria sogar. Seine Sprache ist alles andere als schick.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: du verstehst mich falsch. Jeder Mensch ordnet sich unbewusst der Kultur unter, in der er lebt - eben auch sprachlich. Und das tut er, wenn er so redet, allein schon, wenn er den Dialekt akzeptiert und nicht Hochdeutsch redet.

Comment: Wie gesagt: Wenn du Beispiele anführen könntest, die deine These stützen, käme das der Glaubwürdigkeit deiner Antwort sehr zugute.

Comment: Er hatte mit dem "Wir" so etwas wie "Unsereiner" gemeint, weißt du? Bsp.: Sprössling sagt zur Mutter: "Warum gehst du nicht mal zur Disco?" - sie daraufhin: "Wir gehen doch da nicht mehr hin."

Comment: Nein. Der Sprecher meint nicht eine Gruppe der er angehört, sondern nur ganz alleine sich allein. Sonst niemanden. Er hatte zuvor sein Handy weggeworfen (von einer hohen Brücke in einen Fluss) und wird nach seiner Handynummer gefragt. Diese Frage beantwortet er mit »mia hon khoa händy«

Comment: Woher willst du das wissen? Du interpretierst nur.

Comment: Ich weiß das, weil ich diesen Krimi gesehen habe. Lies bitte die ganze Frage noch einmal, und schenke dabei dem allerersten Satz ganz besondere Aufmerksamkeit. Wir könnten uns die ganze Diskussion hier sparen, wenn du die Frage aufmerksam lesen würdest. Da steht alles drinnen was du wissen must. Einerseits stört es dich, dass ich »immer so einen Roman« schreibe, andererseits stiehlst du uns beiden Zeit weil du ständig neue Details nachfragst. Bitte: Bevor du neue Fragen stellst und dir neue Behauptungen aus der Nase ziehst: Lies bitte die Frage  AUFMERKSAM durch. Da steht alles drin.

Comment: Ich habe mir die Arbeit angetan, aus dem Film die relevanten Szenen heraus zu schneiden und das Notwendigste der Handlung zusammenzufassen. Siehe Abschnitt »Noch mehr Kontext« in meinem Frageposting.

Comment: Ich kenne den "mir"-Effekt ein bisschen von Leuten aus dem Erzgebirge/Vogtland. Die Leute fangen damit auch Sätze gern an. Bedeutet so etwas wie "Meinereiner"...

Answer (score -2):

Im Deutschen wird einem traditionell das Du angeboten. Vorher wird sich nur mit dem Familiennamen angeredet. Eine Familie ist aber eine Gruppe von Personen.

Um die Beziehung Symmetrisch zu halten muss der Sprecher sowohl sich als auch den angeredeten in der gleichen Ebene anreden.

Beispiel: 1. Person Singular spricht mit 2. Person Singular

> Ich spreche mit Dir (Mein Sohn).

Beispiel: 1. Person Plural spricht mit 2. Person Plural

> Wir sprechen mit Euch/Ihnen (Mein Herr).

Daher würde es für mich Sinn ergeben, wenn man sich selbst im **Allgemeinfall** in der Öffentlichkeit immer im Plural anspricht, ausser man spricht im **Spezialfall** direkt mit einer Person in der das Du normalerweise Verwendet wird.

Comment: Sorry, das ist leider einfach nur falsch und sonst nichts. Wenn ich als Einzelperson mit einer Gruppe von 20 Leuten spreche, benutze ich trotzdem immer die Einzahl wenn ich von mir spreche. Dabei ist es egal, ob ich niemanden, einige oder alle Leute aus der Gruppe duze. Darüber hinaus fällt der Satz in dem Film zumindest beim zweiten Mal gegenüber nur einer einzigen Person.

Comment: Symmetrie ist übrigens auch bei der Höflichkeitsform kein Muss. Wenn sich Kinder mit fremden Erwachsenen unterhalten, werden die Kinder die Erwachsenen mit »Sie« ansprechen, die Erwachsenen werden aber »du« benutzen wenn sie mit den Kindern reden. Und die Behauptung »*Im Deutschen wird einem traditionell das Du angeboten.*« kann ich auch nicht nachvollziehen. Ich biete sehr selten jemandem das Du-Wort an, und man bietet es mir auch selten an (worüber ich übrigens auch froh bin).

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ich denke, der Satz "das 'du' wird einem angeboten" (oder eben nicht) sollte gutmütig mit einer Betonung auf dem letzen Wort verstanden sein - Man "nimmt es sich nicht selbst", wie in vielen anderen Kulturkreisen.

Comment: »Sprechen Sie mit mir?«, ist ein vollkommen normaler deutscher Satz, in dem deine scheinbare Asymmetrie vorkommt und von niemandem beanstandet wird. Es ist nämlich mitnichten so, dass die grammatikalische Pluralform »Sie« (ähnlich »Euch«) aus Höflichkeit einen Plural der 1. Person verlangen würde.