# Auf wen bezieht sich hier „dessen“ (als Possessivartikel)?

Tags: article, demonstrative-pronoun

Meine Frage geht um *Das Parfum*. Der Schriftsteller schreibt:

> Der Tuchhändler Alexandre Misnard erschoß seinen eigenen Hausdiener
> bei dessen nächtlicher Heimkehr, weil er ihn für den berüchtigen
> Mädchenmörder hielt.

[Mir wurde einmal erklärt](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/66098/warum-benutzt-dieser-schriftsteller-deren-statt-ihre), dass sich „dessen“ in so einem Fall auf die weniger naheliegende Person beziehen würde. Aber ich bin nicht sicher, wer das wäre. Ist der Hausdiener „naheliegender“, weil das Wort „Hausdiener“ im Satz buchstäblich näher an „dessen“ liegt? In diesem Fall würde es um die Heimkehr des Tuchhändlers gehen, was Sinn machen würde. Aber in der übertragenen Bedeutung von „naheliegender“, d.h. wahrscheinlicher, kommt es mir naheliegender vor, dass der Tuchhändler derjenige ist, der heimgekehrt ist, weil es meiner Meinung nach natürlicher wäre, dass der Besitzer des Heims heimkehren würde, was wie gesagt ganz sinnvoll wäre. In diesem Fall würde sich „dessen“ auf den Hausdiener beziehen.

Ich wäre dankbar für nicht nur eine Antwort zu meiner im Subjekt stehenden Frage, sondern auch eine Erklärung davon, warum „dessen“ statt „seinen“ benutzt wurde.

Answer (score 2):

Nein. *Dessen* bezieht sich hier auf den Hausdiener. Wenn der Tuchhändler gemeint wäre, würde man den Satz so formulieren müssen:

> Der Tuchhändler Alexandre Misnard erschoß bei seiner nächtlichen Heimkehr seinen eigenen Hausdiener, weil er ihn für den berüchtigen Mädchenmörder hielt.

Hier steht das Adverbial auch vor dem Akkusativobjekt, da nur dadurch klar ist, dass sich der durch das Adverbial beschriebene Umstand auf das Subjekt bezieht.

Die beiden Möglichkeiten

> Der Tuchhändler Alexandre Misnard erschoß seinen eigenen Hausdiener bei seiner nächtlichen Heimkehr, weil er ihn für den berüchtigen Mädchenmörder hielt.

und

> Der Tuchhändler Alexandre Misnard erschoß bei dessen nächtlicher Heimkehr seinen eigenen Hausdiener, weil er ihn für den berüchtigen Mädchenmörder hielt.

sind zweideutig. Man sollte sie daher vermeiden.

Comment: Janka, danke. Wenn die Position vom Adverbial die Sache regelt, warum sind die zwei anderen Möglichkeiten zweideutig? Entschuldigung, ich habe meine Frage bearbeitet, um klarer (bzw. überhaupt klar) zu sein, dass ich mich über eine weitere Erklärung der Entscheidung des Schriftstellers freuen würde,

Comment: Weil die Position es eben nicht regelt. Im Deutschen dienen die Positionen im Satz der Betonung. Jedes Satzglied hat eine typische Position, und wenn man es an eine andere Stelle setzt, wird es besonders betont. Das ist bei den zweideutigen Varianten der Fall.

Comment: Ich denke, dass die Antwort verbessert werden kann, wenn du eine Erklärung über den Unterschied  zwischen "der/dessen" und "er/seinen" gibst. Z.B. (ohne Anspruch auf Korrektheit) "er" könne nur Vorangeganges beschreiben und "der" nur im Satz direkt Benachbartes.

Comment: Wenn dir was Passendes einfällt, kannst du es auch gerne selbst ergänzen.

Comment: Ich finde die letzte Variante (ohne weteren Kontext) überhaupt nicht zweideutig. Das Wort "dessen" bedeutet da klar, dass nicht die Heimkehr des Tuchhändlers selbst gemeint sein kann.

Comment: @Janka: In welcher Form ergänzen? Nach [diesem Online-Paper](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/les-2018-0008/html?lang=de) und dem [Abstract eines anderen](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/251400128_The_Non-Subject_Bias_of_German_Demonstrative_Pronouns) bevorzugt "er" das Subjekt und "der" meidet es. Also wären alle Sätze eindeutig: "der" ist immer der Diener und "er" ist immer Misnard. Ich möchte nicht große Teile in deine Antwort schreiben.

Comment: Janka, ich fürchte, ich verstehe noch nicht. Nehmen wir deine erste zweideutige Variante. Ich verstehe, dass sie zweideutig ist, aber wie ist der Gebrauch von "dessen" eine Lösung? Da ich nicht weiß, auf wen "dessen" sich überhaupt bezieht, bleibt der Satz zumindest für mich zweideutig!

Comment: *Dessen* bezieht sich auf das, auf das *seiner* sich nicht bezieht. Sonst könnte man ja *seiner* schreiben.

Comment: Janka, du hast gerade geschrieben, dass diese Variante zweideutig ist, wenn sie mit "seiner" geschrieben wird. Das heißt, ich weiß nicht, auf was "seiner" sich bezieht, daher weiß ich natürlich auch nicht, auf was "seiner" sich *nicht* bezieht, daher kann ich nicht feststellen, auf was "dessen" sich bezieht.

Comment: *Seiner* bezieht sich primär auf das Subjekt, weil zuvor ja bereits mit dem anderen *seiner* auf das Subjekt Bezug genommen wurde.

Comment: Ok, aber wie wäre es ohne das erste *seinen*: „Der Tuchhändler Alexandre Misnard erschoß den Hausdiener bei seiner nächtlichen Heimkehr.“ Ist es auch so hier, dass sich *seiner* wohl auf das Subjekt bezieht, und es besser wäre, *dessen* zu benutzen, wenn es um die Heimkehr des Hausdieners geht?

Comment: Dieses *seiner* bezieht sich dann eher auf das Objekt.

Answer (score 0):

> Ist der Hausdiener „naheliegender“, weil das Wort „Hausdiener“ im Satz buchstäblich näher an „dessen“ liegt? In diesem Fall würde es um die Heimkehr des Tuchhändlers gehen, was Sinn machen würde.

Ja und nein. Die logische Abfolge im Satz stellt "deren" in Bezug zu dem "Hausdiener", so dass eine zusammenhängende Wortgruppe "Hausdiener bei dessen nächtlicher Heimkehr" ohne weiteres als Einheit begriffen werden kann.

Das betrifft entgegen deines Kommentars nicht den Tuchhändler, weshalb fraglich bleibt, was du sonst mit "buchstäblich" meinst.

---

Der Kommentar, aus dem du zitierst (@Olafant),  steht dieser Ansicht nicht entgegen. Es bedeutet aber etwas anderes, denn *naheliegend* wird in der regel adverbial verwendet und bedeutet damit so viel wie "plausibel" (DWDS: [naheliegend](https://www.dwds.de/wb/naheliegend)). Ansonsten wäre *nächstgelegen* vorzuziehen, also "räumlich am nächsten gelegen, am wenigsten weit entfernt" (DWDS: [nächstgelegen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/n%C3%A4chstgelegen)), ist hier aber nicht gegeben.

Dabei war die Grundaussage der Antworten zu der Frage über dem Kommentar eine andere, die auch hier zutrifft: "Davon abgesehen, dass *deren* (wie @Arno in seiner inzwischen gelöschten Antwort m.E. ganz richtig schrieb) eine größere **Distanz** zum Ausdruck bringt, spielt hier auch die Grammatik eine Rolle." (@Olafant). Das betrifft im wesentlichen die Unterscheidung von anderen Relativpronomen. Der Wortlaut, "Distanz", könnte immerhin zu Verwirrung führen.

> Aber in der übertragenen Bedeutung von „naheliegender“, d.h. wahrscheinlicher, kommt es mir naheliegender vor, dass der Tuchhändler derjenige ist, der heimgekehrt ist,

*Naheliegend* und das daraus abzuleitende Vollverb *nahelegen* ~ *nahegelegt* werden nie explizit mit räumlichem Bezug verwendet.<sup>[*]</sup>

> ... weil es meiner Meinung nach natürlicher wäre, dass der Besitzer des Heims heimkehren würde, was wie gesagt ganz sinnvoll wäre.

Das ist offensichtlich unbegründet.

Zumindest historisch war das Haus des Herrn auch des Hausdieners Bleibe. Seine Heimat könnte woanders liegen, doch hinter dieser besonderen Bedeutung steht *Heim* als Synonym zu *Haus* zurück. Es ist wiederum Zufall, dass auch in der Heimat noch ein Heim sein kann. *Heimkehr* kann daher beides bezeichnen. Vermutlich spielt altfränkisch *ham-* "mit" dabei eine Rolle, vgl. lat. *com-*, *convene* "Zusammentreffen". Es ist insoweit relativ egal, wer gemeint ist. Über die Bewegung des anderen wird schließlich nichts gesagt. Es ergibt sich pragmatischer Weise aus dem Kontext, weil Hinterhalt als Modus Operandi zu vermuten ist, dass der Schütze dem Ziel auflauerte, um den jenigen zu erschießen.

Die Grammatik wurde in der Frage bereits besprochen, auf die du verwiesen hast. Dabei ging es vorallem um die Alternative mit reflexiven Pronomen *ihr-* (bzw. in unserem Fall *sein*). In einer anderen Fallgestaltung mit Passiv wird es vielleicht deutlicher, da die Alternative entfällt:

> *Der H, *dessen* Heimkehr erwartet worden war, ist von dem T erschossen worden.

Da passt kein einfaches *sein* rein. Andere Alternativen, etwa dativisch *von dem die*, mögen dahinstehen.

Der eingeschobene Nebensatz ist stilistisch weniger schön, macht nur Sinn, wenn die Information nicht deiktisch, also bereits bekannt ist, wovon hier nach der eingehenden Besprechung jedenfalls auszugehn ist; andernfalls als Stilelement, um die Bekanntheit wenigstens zu suggerieren. Genauso verhält es sich in dem Roman. Es wird der Eindruck einer kurzen, bereits auffeklärten Kriminalgeschichte erweckt.

[*]: Die Bedeutung von *nehel ist nicht auf lexikalischer Ebene übertragen worden. Wenn es sich in ein räumliches Bild fügt, ist das Zufall. Allenfalls wird ein adjektivisches Partizip *nahegelegen* zu *nächstgelegen* zu zählen sein. Der Gleichklang birgt Verwechslungspotential, sodass *nahe liegen* beides heißen kann, *nahe liegen* (etwas liegt nah, ist naheliegend, wurde nahgelegt) bzw. *in der Nähe liegen* (etwas liegt in der Nähe. Der unterschied zwischen intransitiven und transitiven ist übrigens auch auf englischer Sprache zwischen *to lie* bzw. *to lay* nicht immer eindeutig. Behelfsweise ist davon auszugehen, dass *nahelegen* nicht mit Nähe sonder mit *knowledge* < OE *cnawlece* verwandt ist ("The second element is obscure," etymonline: knowledge). Das wäre nur *logisch*. Weil der Verlust des anlautenden K- aber nur durch Folksetymologie mit *nah* erklären lässt, muss das Sinnbild äußerst alt sein. Es handelt sich also um eine ahnständige Metapher (eine ererbte, schlechte Übersetzung).

Answer (score 0):

Zuerst noch einmal der Satz von Patrick Süßkind aus dessen Roman *»das Parfum«*:

> Der Tuchhändler Alexandre Misnard erschoß seinen eigenen Hausdiener bei dessen nächtlicher Heimkehr, weil er ihn für den berüchtigen Mädchenmörder hielt.

Hier ist zumindest klar, dass sich *»er«* im Nebensatz ganz eindeutig auf den Tuchhändler *»ihn«* auf den erschossenen Hausdiener bezieht. Die Grammatik erlaubt nämlich auch hier die umgekehrte Deutung, aber ohne eindeutigen Kontext erscheint diese Interpretation semantisch unsinnig.

Betrachten wir nun zwei Sätze, die nach demselben Muster gestrickt sind:

> 1. Herr Schultz betrachtete den Saft bei dessen Zubereitung, weil er ihn anschließend trinken wollte.
> 2. Herr Schultz betrachtete den Saft bei dessen Ernennung zum Vorsitzenden, weil er ihn anschließend trinken wollte.

Auch hier bezieht sich *»er«* im Nebensatz eindeutig auf das Subjekt (*»Herr Schultz«*) und *»ihn«* auf das Akkusativobjekt (*»den Saft«*). Beide Sätze sind grammatisch korrekt, aber der zweite wirkt etwas holprig, weil sich *»dessen«* im Hauptsatz und *»ihn«* im Nebensatz auf zwei verschiedene Bestandteile des Hauptsatzes beziehen. Im ersten Satz beziehen sich beide Wörter auf den Saft, wodurch der Fokus der Aufmerksamkeit die ganze Zeit auf ihm liegt. Aber im zweiten Satz bezieht sich *»dessen«* auf den Herrn Schultz und *»ihn«* auf den Saft, wodurch im Satz der semantische Fokus wechselt. Das ist zwar grammatisch erlaubt, aber Patrick Süßkind hätte seinen Satz sicherlich nicht nach diesem Schema konstruiert, wenn es seine Absicht gewesen wäre, die Heimkehr des Tuchhändlers zu beschrieben.

Ein zweiter Grund, warum es viel wahrscheinlicher ist, dass der Hausdiener heimgekehrt ist, ist außerhalb der Grammatik im Kontext zu suchen. Der Satz von Tuchhändler ist eine von mehreren Miniatur-Schilderungen von Tragödien, die das Chaos beschreiben, das in Grasse geherrscht hat, nachdem Grenouille dort 24 bildhübsche heranreifende Mädchen bzw. junge Frauen ermordet hatte. Alle in der Stadt hatten Angst um ihre Töchter, und niemand wusste, wer der Mörder war. Und so verdächtigte jeder jeden, wodurch es unter anderem zur irrtümlichen Tötung des Hausdieners kam. Ich habe ans Ende meiner Antwort den Absatz aus dem Roman angefügt in dem der fragliche Satz steht.

**Situation 1:**
Der Hausdiener hütet das Haus. Der Hausherr Misnard war außer Haus, hatte dabei seine Pistole mit und kehrt nun zurück. Der Diener hört seinen Herrn heimkommen und eilt ihm wie immer entgegen, um ihn zu begrüßen. Aber als Misnard sieht, dass im Haus jemand ist, der auf ihn zukommt, glaubt er, dass die heraneilende Person der gesuchte Massenmörder ist, worauf Misnard diese Person erschießt.

**Situation 2:**
Misnard ist den ganzen Tag zuhause. Der Hausdiener war außer Haus und kehrt nun zurück. Als Misnard bemerkt, dass jemand dabei ist, ohne anzuklopfen sein Haus zu betreten, holt er die Pistole aus der Lade seines Schreibtisches, geht damit zur Tür und erschießt den verdächtigen Ankömmling.

Ich halte die erste Situation für unwahrscheinlich, weil es für den heimkehrenden Tuchhändler wohl kaum überraschend war, zuhause seinen Hausdiener anzutreffen. Außerdem müsste er schon zuvor, während er fort war bewaffnet gewesen sein, was zwar nicht ausgeschlossen ist, aber wofür kein plausibler Grund vorhanden ist.

Die zweite Situation ist viel plausibler, weil es durchaus möglich ist, dass Misnard gar nicht bemerkt hat, dass sein Diener fort war. Dann hat der Tuchhändler nicht damit gerechnet, dass jemand ohne anzuklopfen das Haus betritt. Er war erschrocken, und so kam es zur unüberlegten Handlung. Außerdem muss in diese Situation der Tuchhändler nicht von Anfang an mit einer schweren Waffe herumrennen.

---

Kontext:

> Die Menschen empörten sich und beschimpften die
> Obrigkeit. Das kleinste Gerücht führte zu
> Zusammenrottungen. Ein fahrender Händler, der
> Liebespulver und andere Quacksalbereien verkaufte,
> wurde fast massakriert, denn es hieß, seine Mittelchen
> enthielten gemahlenes Mädchenhaar. Auf das Hotel de
> Cabris und auf das Hospiz der Charite wurden
> Brandanschläge verübt. **Der Tuchhändler Alexandre
> Misnard erschoß seinen eigenen Hausdiener bei dessen
> nächtlicher Heimkehr, weil er ihn für den berüchtigten
> Mädchenmörder hielt.** Wer es sich leisten konnte,
> schickte seine heranwachsenden Töchter zu entfernten
> Verwandten oder in Pensionate nach Nizza, Aix oder
> Marseille. Der Polizeilieutenant wurde auf Drängen des
> Stadtrats seines Postens enthoben. Sein Nachfolger ließ
> die Leichen der geschorenen Schönheiten von einem
> Ärztekollegium auf ihren virginalen Zustand
> untersuchen. Es fand sich, daß sie alle unberührt
> geblieben waren.
>
> Aus: Das Parfum von Patrick Süßkind

Comment: Danke für die Antwort, und du lieferst eine gute Argumentation dafür, was narrativ sinnvoller wäre, die Grammatik abgesehen. Würdest du sagen, dass in deinen zwei Beispielsätzen, die jeweilige Bevorzugung von »dessen« bzw. »seinen« auch unverändert wäre, wenn der Nebensatz (also »weil er ihn...«) nicht da wäre? Wenn ja, deutete das an, dass »seinen« eine Tendenz hätte, sich auf das Satzsubjekt zu beziehen, die der Gebrauch von »dessen« umdreht? Oder hängt diese Sache vollständig von »er ihn« oder Ähnliches ab?

Comment: @cruthers: Hier sind zwei ähnliche Sätze: *1. »Jürgen begrüßte Paul bei seiner Heimkehr.« - 2. »Jürgen begrüßte Paul bei dessen Heimkehr.«* In beiden Sätzen ist mehrdeutig, wer heimkehrt. Anders formuliert: Man kann beide Sätze verwenden, wenn der Kontext vorgibt, dass Jürgen heimkehrt, und man kann beide Sätze verwenden, wenn der Kontext vorgibt, dass Paul der Heimkehrer ist. In keinem dieser Fälle entsteht ein Widerspruch.

Comment: Interessant. Na ich will keinen Streit auslösen, aber laut seinem Kommentar zu seiner Antwort hält @DavidVogt deinen gerade obigen Punkt für falsch! Liegt die Meinungsunterschied vielleicht an unterschiedlichen deutschen Sprachräumen?

Answer (score 0):

Wenn Genitivformen des Demonstrativpronomens *dessen, deren* wie Possessivartikel verwendet werden, können sie sich im Gegensatz zu diesen nicht auf das Subjekt beziehen. Man verwendet also *dessen, deren*, um Mehrdeutigkeit auszuschließen. So in folgendem Beispiel:

> Als sich der Pfarrer<sub>**j**</sub> erhängt […] fühlt sich Höllbacher<sub>**i**</sub> für dessen<sub>**j**</sub> Tod verantwortlich. Er fühlt sich aber auch von Staatsanwalt Nicoletti hintergangen, der sich aus der Affäre zieht und Höllbacher die alleinige Schuld zuschiebt. Höllbacher<sub>**i**</sub> knallt Waffe und Dienstmarke auf Nicolettis<sub>**k**</sub> Tisch und verlässt dessen<sub>**k**</sub> Büro mit den Worten: »I scheiß auf euch olle«. ([Quelle](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/33893/ich-wir-im-s%c3%bcdtiroler-dialekt))

*Dessen* steht sogar in *er fühlt sich für dessen Tod verantwortlich*, wo Bezug auf das Subjekt schon durch die Logik ausgeschlossen ist, aus reiner Gewohnheit – kein Subjektbezug, dann lieber *dessen*.

Der Possessivartikel *sein* wäre dagegen grammatisch mehrdeutig.

> Höllbacher<sub>**i**</sub> knallt Waffe und Dienstmarke auf Nicolettis<sub>**k**</sub> Tisch und verlässt sein<sub>**i,k**</sub> Büro mit den Worten: …

Das Gleiche gilt für das Ausgangsbeispiel.

> Der Tuchhändler Alexandre Misnard<sub>**i**</sub> erschoß seinen eigenen Hausdiener<sub>**j**</sub> bei dessen<sub>**j**</sub> nächtlicher Heimkehr.
>
> Der Tuchhändler Alexandre Misnard<sub>**i**</sub> erschoß seinen eigenen Hausdiener<sub>**j**</sub> bei seiner<sub>**i,j**</sub> nächtlichen Heimkehr.

Comment: Vielen Dank David. Würdest du also @HubertSchölnast widersprechen? Lies mal bitte seinen Kommentar, also den zweiten Kommentar unter seiner Antwort. Er glaubt wohl, dass sich die wie Possessivartikel verwendeten Genitivformen auf das Subjekt beziehen können.

Comment: Das halte ich für falsch. Wenn Subjektbezug ausgeschlossen sein soll, benutzt er selbst *dessen* (das obige Beispiel stammt aus einer Frage, die er hier gestellt hat). Allen Zweiflern würde ich empfehlen, die folgenden Belege zu überfliegen, in denen Subjektbezug nicht vorkommt: https://www.dwds.de/r/?corpus=public&q=auf%20dessen%20Wunsch